# Python Modules run fine in Anaconda prompt but not in windows powershell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

Python Modules run fine in Anaconda prompt but not in windows powershell?

I think I have some enviroment varbile issues, maybe.
I just upgraded python ,Now when I try and run my scripts in windows powershell it says the module is not installed. When you pip list, it does show the modules installed.
I completely removed all versions of python, rebooted, no change.

I only se IDLE 3.7 and IDLE 3.10.9

when I look in add remove programs, I don't see python 3.7